# Jackson - How to convert complex JSON to object from map?

Tags: java, json, jackson

The following code might look complex but is actually simple (and is copy/paste compatible):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonTest {
    @Test
    public void test_complex_json_to_object() throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        final String json = "{\"source[longitude]\":[\"26.3843435\"],\"source[latitude]\":[\"174.78830093\"]}";

        final ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Map<String, Object> json_map = m.readValue(json, Map.class);

        m.convertValue(json_map, Data.class);
    }

    public static class Location {
        public double   latitude;
        public double   longitude;
    }

    public static class Data {
        public Location location;

        @JsonProperty(value = "source[longitude]")
        public void setSource__longitude(final String[] data) { // Invoked.
            System.err.println("longitude");
        }

        @JsonProperty(value = "source[latitude]")
        public void setSource__latitude(final String[] data) { // Invoked.
            System.err.println("latitude");
        }

        public void setLocation(final String[] data) { // NOT Invoked!
            System.err.println("latitude");
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON string is fixed. I get that out of an external service as a map, thus the conversion to Map before converting to the `Data` object.

I'd like to have the `latitude` and `longitude` setters defined within the `Location` object, and not as I'm currently forced to (within `Data`).

Problem is, **Jackson doesn't understand that `source[longitude]` is actually `source.longitude`.**

Any way to solve it?

Comment: I don't think that's valid Json. You should have `source: { longitude: [], latitude: [] }` instead.

Comment: @JoãoSilva I believe so as well, still, need to get along with it

Comment: Can you transform, using Java, the String that cointains JSON before trying to map it with Jackson? I don't think Jackson is able to parse what you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do custom handling; either by writing custom `JsonDeserializer`. Your use case is rather esoteric, so there isn't out-of-box support.
It's kind of like having your own data format living inside JSON, so you need to your own handlers.